# Check multiple strings in one cell against another table to match up values in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

For my example, I have a table with one column where each cell has multiple values. To simplify I'll just use colors. In the second Column, I want a Y or N depending on what those colors say in a separate table. If any of the colors listed match up to a Y, then the result should be a Y overall.

| Color | Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| Blue, Green, Yellow | ? |
| Yellow, Red | ? |
| Red, Blue | ? |
| Red, Green | ? |

In my other table I have a list of each color, and Y or N in a corresponding column

| Color | Y or N |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | Y |
| Yellow | Y |
| Red | N |
| Green | N |

The excepted outcome for the first table should be this:

| Color | Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| Blue, Green, Yellow | Y |
| Yellow, Red | Y |
| Red, Blue | Y |
| Red, Green | N |

So, in Row 1, even though Green is a N, since both Blue or Yellow are a Y, then the outcome is Y.

Comment: Since you've shown no effort in your question, I won't give you a full solution. One thing I might provide is a formula you can use to check if a string (like "Blue, Green, Yellow") contains a smaller string (like "Blue" or "Red"), here it is: `=IF(SUBSTITUTE(C$4,D4,"")=C$4,"Does not contain", "Contains")`. You can use this as a starting point. The idea is that you replace the lookup value by an empty string, and check if any change has been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA solution. Because you have Excel 2013, this might prove difficult to do with built in functions. It might not be possible but I'm not 100% sure about that.

```vb
Function myMatch(ByVal inputString As String, ByVal delim As String, ByVal yonList As Range) As String
    Dim splitInput() As String, yonArr() As Variant
    splitInput = Split(inputString, delim)
    yonArr = yonList
    myMatch = "N"
    For i = 0 To UBound(splitInput)
        For j = 1 To UBound(yonArr)
            If Trim(splitInput(i)) = Trim(yonArr(j, 1)) And yonArr(j, 2) = "Y" Then
                myMatch = "Y"
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Function
```

You can use this function in the worksheet like so:

```
=myMatch(A2;",";$E$2:$F$5)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This worked! I did however need to change it to =myMatch(A2,",",$E$2:$F$5)

Comment: @CW I always forget most people use comma as argument separator. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following formula-

```
=OR(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A2,", "),$E$2:$E$5,$F$2:$F$5)="Y")
```

If need `Y` or `N` as output, then try-

```
=TAKE(SORT(XLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(A2,", "),$E$2:$E$5,$F$2:$F$5),,-1,TRUE),,1)
```

[image]

Comment: I unfortunately do not have the version of Excel that supports XLOOKUP, I have 2013 version. Do you know of any other formulas I could try?

Comment: @CW can you try this, it is based on the solution posted by Harun Sir. But you need to hit the `CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER` --> `=OR(VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<m><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,", ","</b><b>")&"</b></m>","//b"),$E$2:$F$5,2,0)="Y")`

Comment: This partially worked, but if Red or Green (since both at N) were the first value in the cell, it would default to N overall.  So if it were "Red, Yellow" it would return FALSE, but if it were "Yellow, Red" it would return TRUE.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a small set of "Colors" you can use this ugly formula:

```vb
=IF(NOT(ISERROR( FIND( "Y",
   IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND($E$2,A2))),$F$2,"") &
   IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND($E$3,A2))),$F$3,"")&
   IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND($E$4,A2))),$F$4,"") &
   IF(NOT(ISERROR(FIND($E$5,A2))),$F$5,"")))),
"Y","N")
```

It checks per color combination and per color if it occurs and returns Y or N from second table - the result is e.g. for Blue,Gree,Yellow YNY or for Red,Green NN. The outer `IF` then checks this result for at least one Y.

[image]